# Have a UI waypoint arrow rotate in the direction of the to next checkpoint, relative to the player in UE4?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I've been working on developing a UI-component that always points to the next checkpoint as the user plays through the game. My issue is that I don't know how to update the rotation of the arrow in relation to the player and the next checkpoint. With my current setup, the arrow rotates erratically, or spins in circles. I believe the nodes I want to use are the "Find Look at Rotation", "RInterp To", and "Add Rotation."

Here's what I have so far: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsocW.jpg

My player actor is a pawn, the checkpoint is an empty actor class that I have hidden when the game is being played, and the waypoint arrow is a static mesh floating outside the playable environment that I setup a 2DCaptureComponent and green screen, such that I can update the rotations of the waypoint arrow during the game, and the UI will automatically update.

-- Update --

I was able to set the initial rotation of the waypoint arrow correctly using this setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kN7W.jpg

I changed the "Add Rotation" node to "Set World Rotation", and added -90 to the Yaw (to offset the initial orientation of the waypoint arrow). However, after setting the initial rotation, it no longer updates the rotation after the player actor rotates. Any insights?

-- Edit --

Here is the rotation angles of 1) the waypoint arrow in the blueprint capture class, and 2) the rotation of the blueprint instance as it exists in the world: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXgly.jpg

Comment: there should be a "set world rotation" maybe that would work better

Comment: @Ruzihm thank you for your insight! I was able to correctly setup the initial rotation of the actor, however, as my post-update explains, the rotation no longer updates when the actor rotates in the environment. Any insights on that?

Comment: I don't think subtracting from the rotator's y is an appropriate fix for the problem you're seeing. Can you show in the question what the local axes of the arrow look like? There's not enough information to reproduce that problem. btw, subtracting from a rotator's y is a modification to the pitch, (remember, the y axis in unreal is the left-right axis.)

Comment: @Ruzihm updated! Thank you again for your assistance. I've included both the local and world rotations of the waypoint arrow.

Comment: @Ruzihm when I debug the program as it's running, it seems as though the "Get Player Controller" location and rotation do not update. Is this because I'm trying to access the player through an external blueprint (my blueprint capture class)?

Comment: Ohh yes, I overlooked that. You should use GetPlayerPawn then get actor location. And for rotation, I think you can do "Get Player Camera Manager" node then Get Actor Rotation. if you want the camera's rotation.  Or if you want the pawn's rotation you should use getplayerpawn then get actor rotation.

Comment: Rewriting my earlier suggestion. Do you think you can make the mesh component of the arrow a child of the root, then apply the -90 pitch to the local rotation of the mesh's component? I think this will still be necessary even if you get the player rotation/location situation fixed

Comment: @Ruzihm regarding the mesh component, is this already what I'm doing, as shown here: https://imgur.com/a/f96YOXK ? Or is the mesh component still not a child of the root?

Comment: revising. Oh I see it's a static mesh actor. These always have a mesh as the root.  In that case it might be easiest if you create a new bp, child of Actor. Then, add a staticmesh component as a child of the root component, which you can assign the arrow (cone) mesh and give the -90 pitch offset. Then you can use that new actor instead of the static mesh actor you were using.

Comment: @Ruzihm that worked perfectly! Now that the waypoint arrow is a child of Actor and the pitch is set locally, I no longer have to worry about resetting the waypoint arrow's pitch! I'll continue to debug why the actor/camera location/rotation aren't updating. I greatly appreciate you taking time out of your day to help me thus far!

Comment: You're welcome! I summed up the solution below as an answer. Please consider upvoting and [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use <kbd>Set World Rotation</kbd>  instead of <kbd>Add World Rotation</kbd>.

You should use <kbd>Get Player Pawn</kbd> then <kbd>Get Actor Location</kbd>. And for rotation, I think you can do <kbd>Get Player Camera Manager</kbd> then <kbd>Get Actor Rotation</kbd> if you want the camera's rotation. Or, if you want the pawn's rotation, you should use <kbd>Get Player Pawn</kbd> then <kbd>Get Actor Rotation</kbd>.

And to handle the offset you need, implement your arrow as an actor, with the mesh as a <kbd>Static Mesh Component</kbd> which is a child of the root. You can apply the offset you need specifically to the mesh, so that it points in the direction of the actor's local forward.

Source: @denmonz
[image]

Comment: In addition to @Ruzihm's suggestions, I got the waypoint arrow working with the following setup: https://imgur.com/a/aYZz1Lh
It first finds the rotation between the player pawn and the next waypoint, then does some fancy vector maths to translate that angle in terms of the current rotation of the player camera.
Now, the waypoint arrow moves whenever the player pawn moves, and also when the player pawn/camera rotates.